# Error in storing multiple JSON in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb

I am working MQTT in JavaScript. when subscriber is waiting for message, the publisher will publish the message every 1 millisecond.

But in the subscriber side it receives the message but it is giving error while storing to MongoDB.

Below are my code.
Please help me to come out. Thanks in advance.

publisher.js

```js
var mqtt = require('mqtt');  
var url  = 'mqtt://localhost:1883';

/*var payload = {  
  deviceId : '8675309'
};*/

var client = mqtt.connect(url);
var sensorProperty = {};
client.on('connect', function () {
var publishedData = [];
var totalNoData = 100000;
 
setInterval(
      function ()  // Call out to get the time
      {
       console.log(publishedData.length);
        if (publishedData.length < totalNoData) {
        var sensorId = 4001;
       var intervalId = setInterval(
     function(){
         if (sensorId < 9001) {
         sensorProperty["dfsdffsdf"] = sensorId.toString();
         sensorProperty["accountId"] = "1388142455353";
         sensorProperty["dfgdfgf"] = 1;
         sensorProperty["dfgdfgdfg"] = 260;
         sensorProperty["podfgdfgdfgwer"] = 12;
         sensorProperty["timestamp"] = new Date();
         sensorProperty.timestamp.setDate(sensorProperty.timestamp.getDate() - 50);
         sensorProperty.timestamp = new Date(sensorProperty.timestamp).toISOString();
            sensorProperty.timestamp = new Date(sensorProperty.timestamp);
         var message = JSON.stringify(sensorProperty);
         console.log(message)
         client.publish('airasoul', message, { qos: 1 }, function() {
             
           });
         sensorId++;
         }   else {
             clearInterval(intervalId);
             console.log("cycle complete");
         }

     },1)
      }else {
       clearInterval();
       console.log("Exceeds");
      }
     }, 20000);// end check


});
```

Subscriber.js

```js
var mqtt = require('mqtt');  
var url  = 'mqtt://localhost:1883';
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var assert = require('assert');
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
var mongoUrl = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dfgdfgdfgdfgd';

var client = mqtt.connect(url, { clientId: 'mqtt-sub-', clean: false });
var receivedMessage = [];
client.on('connect', function () {  
  client.subscribe('airasoul', { qos: 1 });
});

client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
  receievedMessage = JSON.parse(message.toString()); 
  console.log('received message ',  message.toString());
  MongoClient.connect( mongoUrl, function(err, db) {
   assert.equal(err, null);
 insertDocument(db, function() {
     db.close();
 });
 });
});
 
var insertDocument = function(db, callback) {
    db.collection('sensordata').insertMany([receievedMessage], function(err, result) {
     console.log("Inserted documents into the sensorData collection.");
     console.log(err);
     console.log(result);
     callback();
 });
};
```

Error it is showing,

```js
[MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: powerbankdb.sensordata index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('58a2f56dd190242e789d758d') }]
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: powerbankdb.sensordata index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId(\'58a2f56dd190242e789d758d\') }',
driver: true,
code: 11000,
index: 0,
errmsg: 'E11000 duplicate key error collection: powerbankdb.sensordata index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId(\'58a2f56dd190242e789d758d\') }',
getOperation: [Function],
toJSON: [Function],
toString: [Function] }
ok: [Getter],
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that there exists a duplicate key. Make sure there are no documents that have the same _id ("58a2f56dd190242e789d758d" in this case)

Comment: id is mongo genereated no sir.